# UnitTest coroutines Kotlin usecase MVP

Tags: android, unit-testing, kotlin-coroutines

I am trying to mock a response from my usecases, this usecase works with coroutines.

```
fun getData() {
    view?.showLoading()
    getProductsUseCase.execute(this::onSuccessApi, this::onErrorApi)
}
```

My useCase is injected on presenter.

GetProductsUseCase has this code:

```
class GetProductsUseCase (private var productsRepository: ProductsRepository) : UseCase<MutableMap<String, Product>>() {

    override suspend fun executeUseCase(): MutableMap<String, Product> {
        val products =productsRepository.getProductsFromApi()
        return products
    }
}
```

My BaseUseCase

```
abstract class UseCase<T> {

    abstract suspend fun executeUseCase(): Any

    fun execute(
        onSuccess: (T) -> Unit,
        genericError: () -> Unit) {
        GlobalScope.launch {
            val result = async {
                try {
                    executeUseCase()
                } catch (e: Exception) {
                    GenericError()
                }
            }
            GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.Main) {
                when {
                    result.await() is GenericError -> genericError()
                    else -> onSuccess(result.await() as T)
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

This useCase call my repository:

```
override suspend fun getProductsFromApi(): MutableMap<String, Product> {
    val productsResponse = safeApiCall(
        call = {apiService.getProductsList()},
        error = "Error fetching products"
    )
    productsResponse?.let {
                    return productsMapper.fromResponseToDomain(it)!!
    }
    return mutableMapOf()
}
```

Y try to mock my response but test always fails.

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner::class)
class HomePresenterTest {

    lateinit var presenter: HomePresenter

    @Mock
    lateinit var view: HomeView

    @Mock
    lateinit var getProductsUseCase: GetProductsUseCase

    @Mock
    lateinit var updateProductsUseCase: UpdateProductsUseCase

    private lateinit var products: MutableMap<String, Product>

    private val testDispatcher = TestCoroutineDispatcher()
    private val testScope = TestCoroutineScope(testDispatcher)

    @Mock
    lateinit var productsRepository:ProductsRepositoryImpl

    @Before
    fun setUp() {
        Dispatchers.setMain(testDispatcher)
        products = ProductsMotherObject.createEmptyModel()
        presenter = HomePresenter(view, getProductsUseCase, updateProductsUseCase, products)
    }

    @After
    fun after() {
        Dispatchers.resetMain()
        testScope.cleanupTestCoroutines()
    }

    //...

    @Test
    fun a() = testScope.runBlockingTest {
        setTasksNotAvailable(productsRepository)
        presenter.getDataFromApi()

        verify(view).setUpRecyclerView(products.values.toMutableList())
    }

    private suspend fun setTasksNotAvailable(dataSource: ProductsRepository) {
        `when`(dataSource.getProductsFromApi()).thenReturn((mutableMapOf()))
    }
}
```

I don't know what is happening. The log says:

```
"Wanted but not invoked:
view.setUpRecyclerView([]);
-> at com.myProject.HomePresenterTest$a$1.invokeSuspend(HomePresenterTest.kt:165)

However, there was exactly 1 interaction with this mock:
view.showLoading();"
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is with how you create your `GetProductsUseCase`.

You're not creating it with the `mocked` version of your `ProductsRepository`, yet you're mocking the `ProductsRepository` calls.

Try to create the `GetProductsUseCase` manually and not using a `@Mock`

```
// no @Mock
lateinit var getProductsUseCase: GetProductsUseCase


@Before
fun setUp() {
    // ...
    // after your mocks are initialized...
    getProductsUseCase = GetProductsUseCase(productsRepository) //<- this uses mocked ProductsRepository
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! It works. One extra question if is possible. When I return mutableMapOf(), how can I force error response? I tried to return a exception but function require mutableMap.

Comment: @ArisGuimerá I'm not sure if that's what you're askin for, but you can use `thenThrow` instead of `thenReturn` in the `when(dataSource.getProductsFromApi())` statement